# preference file location

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node("c:/test.txt");
System.out.println(prefs.get("aa", "not found"));
prefs.put("aa", "bb");
```

which works fine (the first time it shows "not found" and after it shows "bb").

But I can't find my test.txt file.

Any idea where it is ?

Comment: What makes you think this code would create a file test.txt? You just named a node of the preferences tree, stored in an OS-specific backing store (the Windows registry, AFAIK), 'c:/test.txt'. Read the API documentation.

Comment: well I was misled by a code that says `prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(config.storageFileName);` so I tought it was an actual file.. my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `Preferences` are not stored in files (to do that you should dump them manually using `OutputStream` - `Preferences.exportNode(OutputStream stream);`). On Windows they are stored under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\JavaSoft\Prefs`. So there you will find node "c:\" and node "test.txt" under it.

Comment: yes indeed the entry is there. I was misled by this piece of code `Preferences.userRoot().node(config.storageFileName);` so I was looking for an actual file.